# Add content to a rich html field on a pagelayout

Tags: page-layout, display-template, richhtmlfield

I have a page layout and in this page layout there is a rich html field. I am wanting this rich html field to have 2 columns whether it be done by a table or two divs within the rich html field. Is there anyway you can do this programmatically? Is there a display template or something for rich html fields.
Or is the only way to do this have two fields one column 1 the other column 2 and just use css to use them side by side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about creating a page layout with 2 columns, and putting a rich text field web part in each of the web part zones?

Comment: So the second answer that I put you think is best?